SQL full outer join - when I want to exclude intersection part, why equal is used in join condition while values are never equal?
I have rows either in table t1 or in table t2. Both table have the common field id and name, and id is either null for t1 or t2(it cannot be in both table at the same time). Now I want to select all rows in both tables, either in t1 or in t2, as long as name matches a pattern.
create table t1 (name varchar(20), id integer);
create table t2 (name varchar(20), id integer);
insert into t1 (name, id) values ('Ellen Joe', 1);
insert into t2 (name, id) values ('Shishiron', 2);
insert into t1 (name, id) values ('Watame', 3);
insert into t2 (name, id) values ('Lamy', 4);

Then I am using now an full (outer) join like this:
select 
  *
from
  t1
full outer join
  t2
on
  t1.id = t2.id
where
  t1.name like '%Joe%'
  and
  t2.id is null
or
  t2.name like '%Joe%'
and
  t1.id is null
;

        NAME    ID    NAME    ID
____________ _____ _______ _____
Ellen Joe        1

The result is what I want. But: why the join condition uses = while the values are never equal? Because when one is null the other  is never null. When I use t1.id != t2.id nothing is returned, even syntaxically this is allowed:
SQL> select *
  2  from
  3    t1
  4  full outer join
  5    t2
  6  on
  7    t1.id != t2.id
  8  where
  9    t1.name like '%Shishiron%'
 10    and
 11    t2.id is null
 12  or
 13    t2.name like '%Shishiron%'
 14    and
 15    t1.id is null
 16* ;

no rows selected

I read that the join condition can be anything, just like in WHERE clause. (From MS MYSQL reference). But if it is used for filtering somehow, I don't understand why it's like this in my case.
Demo: https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=7df270bd-78d4-422e-8661-58058e06d81f

If I take your problem statement at face value, then you should not be joining t1 and t2 tables at all, and especially not on some random id number that never matches.
You can write one query on t1 that returns all records containing "Joe" and write a similar query on t2.  The question is how to combine those two queries to produce a single result set?  SQL defines a UNION query operator to do exactly that.  So,
Select name, 't1' as tablename, id
  From t1
  Where name like '%Joe%'
Union All
Select name, 't2', id
  From t2
  Where name like '%Joe%'

That will identify matching records from both tables and tells you which tables they are in.

Initially the tables are actually two tables in Oracle database, containing both a column named SQL_ID. They both contain the SQL executed in the past, one contains more recent history while the other older. Once some configured time passed, the rows will move from table 1 to table 2. So the columns are actually not random IDs, they are both SQL_ID.

But union all makes more sense than join; they are exclusive after all. Thanks

So the original query returns correct result is pure coincidence? Could you elaborate why it could work, in a full outer join, while != does not work?

Your comment above about the ids tells me that the same id is never in both tables at once, so one of the two in your full join is going to be NULL.  This allows your Where test to work.  Had the ids overlapped it would have failed because neither id would be NULL and records would not have appeared.

Yes Chris that was my doubt from the beginning: when the IDs will never coincide(one is non-null while another is null), but my original query has join .. on t1.id = t2.id, and it got the same result as your union all query. I will use Union All from now on, but I wonder why my wrong query got correct result, while join on xxx = yyy does not make sense.

The intent of this query is to limit the rows in the two table and then do a full join.  In this case it works, but it's ugly and confusing to read.  Instead you can use derived tables to apply the where clause constraint, and then join those together.
The query in your fiddle can be re-written like so:
SELECT
*
FROM
(select * from t1 where name like '%Joe%') t1
full outer join (select * from t2 where name like '%Joe%') t2
    on t1.id = t2.id;


But in the subquery tables, the id still are not the same. I don't understand how it is different? Can you elaborate?

Correct, they are not the same. The query above will return one row.  All the columns from t1 will be populated, because there is a row with a name like Joe.  It will return null for the t2 columns because that derived table returns nothing.

Sorry, I didn't make it clear; I wanted to ask how your proposal is different from my query; they both return the same results(1 row, 4 columns, 2 column with values from t1, 2 columns null). And most importantly, the join is still using condition t1.id = t2.id while it is not the case.

They both return the same result.  The re-written query is easier to read, follows best practices, etc.
